# Why CSS padding is inherited from ul to il

Tags: css

In a code example an `ul`'s padding was set to 0

```
nav ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

and all the ul items and sub-items had their padding set to 0 too as it was inherited from the ul and that was strange for me because the padding property doesn't have inheritance so why this happens ?

[image]

Comment: Properties which are in the light grey color are **not** inherited. It is trying to show that none is inherited from the `ul`. For example, if you add a `cursor: pointer` to the `ul` (`cursor` is an inherited property) and inspect the `li`, you'd see the color difference. That property would have a darker color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't happen. Blame Chrome's devtools.

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding-left: 100px;
}
li {
  border: 1px solid red;
  /* Does not inherit padding */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Bar</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It is shown in grey in the screenshot in question. As far as I know, if in grey it is *not* inherited. The ones actually inherited would get shown in a darker color. (*Edit:* Sorry, wanted to post that comment under the question and clicked the wrong button/link.)

Comment: @Bardelman Padding adds some space between the border and the content. You can see in my example that there is space between the blue (ul's) border and the li, but no space between the red borders (li's) and the text.